# "make somebody feel an idiot" or "make somebody feel like an idiot"?

Tags: grammar

I used lingoes software to search for the definition of *snub*, and there is a sentence in *Collins Cobuild Advanced Learner's English Dictionary* that reads

> He snubbed her in public and made her feel an idiot...

I was wondering why is it not "made her feel **like** an idiot"?

Comment: It is delightfully ambiguous isn't it? *I feel an idiot* could mean I am touching a foolish person, but in real life it never does, it expresses *how* someone feels. *I feel/He feels cold/hot/beautiful/ugly/smart/dumb*. But with a noun it's *I feel / He feels an idiot / a fool / a god* etc.

Comment: Though one might expect an adverb, the use of a noun is fine. *Feel foolish* is not very different from *feel a fool.* Well taken.

Answer (score 1):

I read it as a difference between UK and US english.  In the US you'd say "like an idiot", but I've heard UK speakers say it the other way.